# Jquery function on a given form, when many forms on my page

Tags: jquery, select, input

I have a form that repeats many times on my page (it's on a forum).
I have built some kind of a jquery function that basically do the following :

when the SELECT OPTION with value "custom" is selected,

- hide the select
- show a div with textarea inside and focus it

when input is blurred and empty

- hide the input
- "reset" the select by showing it and select it's default (empty value) option

Problem is, I made it for ONE form on my page. And it works.
But when I tried it on a multi-form test page, my function 
- hide the select of every form
- show a div with textarea inside and focus it for every form.

Which is of course not I want to do.

Question : how to make these functions form-specific ?

Here is my code below.

**JQUERY**

```
$("div[name=customInput]").hide();
$("select[name=motifs]").show();

$("select[name=motifs]").change(function () 
{
    if( $("select[name=motifs]").val() == "custom" )
    {   
        $("select[name=motifs]").hide();
        $("div[name=customInput]").show();
        $("textarea[name=customMotif]").focus();
    }
});
$("textarea[name=customInput]").blur ( function () 
{
    if( !$(this).val() ) 
    {
        $("div[name=customMotif]").hide();
        $("select[name=motifs]").show();
        $("select[name=motifs] option[name=motif]").attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});

$('textarea[name=customMotif]').keyup(function() {
            var len = this.value.length;
            if (len >= 150) {
                this.value = this.value.substring(0, 150);
            }
            $('span[name=charLeft]').text(150 - len);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="note.php" method="post" name="notation" id="notation">
<select name="motifs">
        <option value="" name="void">Motif</option>
        <option value="custom" name="custom">Custom</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div name="customInput">
        <textarea cols="30" name="customMotif"/>
        </textarea>
        <span name="charLeft">150</span> Characters left </div>
</form>
```

Thanks for your help; I'm a beginner and still learning how to make things right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to have separate id's or names for each form (if this is a form with posts, you can append post id to the id of the form, for example).  Then in your JS you can apply your logic to $(#requirediv)

Comment: thanks; and how can I apply my logic dynamically to the right ID ? isn't there a this. syntax or something that I do not know that could do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("select[name=motifs]").change(function () 
{
    if( $(this).val() == "custom" )
    {   
        var $parentForm=$(this).closest("form");

        $parentForm.find("select[name=motifs]").hide();
        $parentForm.find("div[name=customInput]").show();
        $parentForm.find("textarea[name=customMotif]").focus();
    }
});
```

`closest` will get the closest ancestor that meets the selector.  In this case the form which the select is contained within.  Then using `find` will find the selectors only within the parent form.

As a side note, IDs should always be unique.